# Timeline Chart not appear

Tags: php, mysql, timeline

I need to monitor machine status and make a timeline.
Data are collected from Mysql table, converted in Json format and (theoretically) timeline should show up.

Everything works well, from getting Mysql data, top converting into Json and printing out to verify it:
{"cols":[{"label":"Macchina","type":"string"},{"label":"Stato","type":"string"},{"label":"Inizio","type":"date"},{"label":"Fine","type":"date"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"2"},{"v":"PROD"},{"v":"Date(2019, 4, 9, 10, 43, 17)"},{"v":"Date(2019, 4, 10, 10, 43, 24)"}]},{"c":[{"v":"1"},{"v":"ALL"},{"v":"Date(2019, 4, 6, 2, 3, 35)"},{"v":"Date(2019, 4, 6, 2, 0, 0)"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2"},{"v":"SET"},{"v":"Date(2019, 4, 6, 16, 0, 51)"},{"v":"Date(2019, 4, 6, 19, 0, 0)"}]},{"c":[{"v":"3"},{"v":"PROD"},{"v":"Date(2019, 4, 7, 14, 4, 43)"},{"v":"Date(2019, 4, 7, 14, 39, 41)"}]}]}

But no chart appears. No error
Why???

```
<html>
<head>

    <title>Grafico Stati Macchina</title>
      <script type = "text/javascript" src = "https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js">
      </script>
      <script type = "text/javascript" src = "https://www.google.com/jsapi">
      </script>
      <script type = "text/javascript">
         google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['timeline']});     
      </script>
</head>
<body>


<?php
$// Initialize variable for database credentials
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = 'root';
$dbname = 'rp_rproject';

//Create database connection
  $dblink = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

//Check connection was successful
  if ($dblink->connect_errno) {
     printf("Failed to connect to database");
     exit();
  }

//Initialize array variable
  $dbdata = array();
  // Aggiunta
  $rows = array();
  $table = array();

$table['cols'] = array(
array('label' => 'Macchina', 'type' => 'string'),
array('label' => 'Stato', 'type' => 'string'),
array('label' => 'Inizio', 'type' => 'date'),
array('label' => 'Fine', 'type' => 'date'),
);

//Fetch 3 rows from actor table
  $result = $dblink->query("SELECT * FROM allarmi2");

  /* Extract the information from $result */
foreach($result as $r) 
{
  // This conversion because JSON doesen't take Date Object
  // assumes dates are patterned 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss'

  preg_match('/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})\s(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/', $r["Inizio"], $match);
  //$date = date('D M d Y H:i:s O',$r['time-on'], $match);
  $year = (int) $match[1];
  $month = (int) $match[2] - 1; // convert to zero-index to match javascript's dates
  $day = (int) $match[3];
  $hours = (int) $match[4];
  $minutes = (int) $match[5];
  $seconds = (int) $match[6];

  $temp = array();
  $temp[] = array('v' => $r['Descrizione']);
  $temp[] = array('v' => $r['Note']);
  $temp[] = array('v' => "Date($year, $month, $day, $hours, $minutes, $seconds)");


  preg_match('/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})\s(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/', $r["Fine"], $match);
  //$date = date('D M d Y H:i:s O',$r['time-off'], $match);
  $year = (int) $match[1];
  $month = (int) $match[2] - 1; // convert to zero-index to match javascript's dates
  $day = (int) $match[3];
  $hours = (int) $match[4];
  $minutes = (int) $match[5];
  $seconds = (int) $match[6];
  $temp[] = array('v' => "Date($year, $month, $day, $hours, $minutes, $seconds)");

  $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
}

$table['rows'] = $rows;

// convert data into JSON format
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);

//Print array in JSON format
 echo json_encode($table);

//close the connection
mysql_close($dbhandle);

?>

 <div id = "container">
      </div>
      <script language = "JavaScript">

    function drawChart() {
        var dataTable = google.visualization.DataTable(<?php echo json_encode($table, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK) ?>);
        //var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?php echo $jsonTable; ?>);
        var options = { colors: ['orange','green','blue','yellow','violet'],
             timeline: { showRowLabels: true ,groupByRowLabel:true, colorByRowLabel: false}, 
             avoidOverlappingGridLines: false};

 // Instantiate and draw the chart.
            var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(document.getElementById('container'));
            chart.draw(dataTable, options);
    }
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I assume you do not have error_reporting switched on. What is the purpose of `mysql_close($dbhandle);`?

Comment: `mysql_close` has no place being in this code, at all, since this is clearly `mysqli` code. Delete that line. It's probably causing errors because that's the wrong type of handle.

Comment: Tip: If you want to quickly format a string, you can use [`sprintf`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) instead of this *assign-lots-of-variables-with-int-casting-and-then-use-string-interpolation* approach. You should also organize this code into functions so that it's not one long, sprawling main boxy and then you can have more code re-use on things like date parsing.